# Angular - Collapsible row with a dynamic id based on the object

Tags: angular

I'm having troubles doing a collapsible row. What I want to do is add an ID to the hidden row, and use the id of the object I'm calling.
But I'm not sure about the syntaxis.

I found an example and changed a bit of things and it works for just one row, but the button applies to every hidden row, I'm missing adding an ID on the row it's hidden or something like that.

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let info of infos; let i = index">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" 
              (click)="isCollapsed = !isCollapsed" 
               [attr.aria-expanded]="!isCollapsed" aria-controls="isCollapsed">
                Toggle
            </button>
        </td>
        <td>{{info.name}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr [attr.id]="collapsed1" [ngbCollapse]="isColapsed">
        <td>Extra info</td>
        <td>as</td>
    </tr>
</ng-container>
```

Also, I'm a bit lost with how [ngbCollapse], [attr.aria-expanded] and aria-controls.

What's the easiest way to do this? 
The objects I'm using contain id's that are not in any particular order.

Comment: Can you create a simple https://stackblitz.com

Comment: each "info" must have its own property: "isCollapsed". So replace all isCollapsed by info.isCollapsed (5 times). NOTE: the last you have isColapsed, replace this one too